# MySQL ER diagram, chen notations explaination

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram, erd

I have a question. For an assignment in uni I've got the task to create an ER diagram using chen notations. The only problem is that when I turned it in, they said I was not using chen notations. Am I wrong here, or isn't this an ER diagram using chen notations? As you can see, I made it in MySQL workbench. Any feedback on the subject would be appreciated. I have googled chen notations and by what I can see, this diagram follows the standard.

[image: MySQL workbench ERD]

Best regards

Comment: as a wanna be software engineer, you should be able to understand a diagram. google for chen notation again, and compare the various diagrams in the wiki page you get as a result, with the diagram generated by workbench.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL Workbench doesn't support the Chen notation. See menu -> Model -> Relationship Notation for the available modes. Classic maybe closest, but there are things still missing (in particular the relationship annotation).

MySQL Workbench only models features from EER that can be represented in a database. Hence things like inheritance aren't possible in models.